# Push to a new view controller without previous controllers (but animated)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to push from ViewController1 to ViewController2, without ViewController1 in the navigation stack. (animated)

This will not have animation:

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [ViewController2()]
```

This will not have animation too:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [ViewController2()]
    }
```

This doesn't have any animation as well:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewContorller2(), animated: true)
```

What is the proper way to animate a push from to ViewController2 (without back button to view controller 1)?

Comment: You want to push twice of time ? for example from currentViewController to newViewController1 then quickly to newViewController2 without animating newViewController1.

Comment: no I mean I want to push with animation, from VC1 to VC2, without the back button. I have found an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([ViewController2()],animated:true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this below, I test it on my phone, it is ok. `func btnClickedHandler()` is a button click handler when touch up inside event happens.

```
func btnClickedHandler()
{
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController2(), animated: true)

    self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeFirst()
}
```